# Limiting events to current month

Tags: fullcalendar

How does one limit the entries on the month to just the month? I don't want to see the events from the end of the prior month and the beginning of the next month.

Comment: Just found this in the issue tracker:Issue 166:  Option to hide day numbers/events/cells for prev/next months

Comment: You can filter your events yourself using a function for the events. Just loop through your event list and check event month compared to current month and push matches to a new array to pass to callback.